Keeping initial part of \item with \lstinputlisting: \minipage works, but blank line before/between items goes away
I want a way to keep each item in an enumeration list together, i.e., not be split across a page — but I only care that the first sentence of the list item (that is short and never is more than one line) is kept together with the following lstlisting. If the list item has additional text after it, I don't care if that's put onto the next page.
Below, in a minimal working example (MWE), I came up with my own keeptogether environment based on this answer.  It works, but the problem is that the blank line before and between list items goes away.  In the MWE, if I remove the keeptogether stuff, then the blank line before the item comes back (which is what I want).
I found that I can compensate for the missing blank line by inserting a \bigskip before the \begin{keeptogether}, but, ideally, I shouldn't have to do that.
How can I get what I want (that is, keep the first line and following lstlisting together), but not have the space before/between items go away (and not have to compensate by inserting a \bigskip)?
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  escapechar=@,
  floatplacement=hbt!,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}

\newenvironment{keeptogether}
  {\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
  {\end{minipage}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\raggedbottom
\mainmatter

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{keeptogether}
\item
Some short sentence:
\begin{lstlisting}
#define IS_UNSIGNED_EXPR(E)                     \
  _Generic( (E),                                \
    bool              : true,                   \
    char              : IS_UNSIGNED_TYPE(char), \
    unsigned char     : true,                   \
    unsigned short    : true,                   \
    unsigned int      : true,                   \
    unsigned long     : true,                   \
    unsigned long long: true,                   \
    default           : false                   \
  )
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{keeptogether}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


You can put your lstlisting in a minipage to ensure it doesn't get broken, and put a \nobreak in front of it to make sure it sticks to the line above it (though you need to put a \par or blank line after your first sentence to end that line):
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  escapechar=@,
  floatplacement=hbt!,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}

\newenvironment{keeptogether}
  {\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
  {\end{minipage}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\raggedbottom
\mainmatter

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
\item
Some short sentence:\par\nobreak
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
#define IS_UNSIGNED_EXPR(E)                     \
  _Generic( (E),                                \
    bool              : true,                   \
    char              : IS_UNSIGNED_TYPE(char), \
    unsigned char     : true,                   \
    unsigned short    : true,                   \
    unsigned int      : true,                   \
    unsigned long     : true,                   \
    unsigned long long: true,                   \
    default           : false                   \
  )
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}



That seems to work. It also seems to work if I just redefine my keeptogether environment to include the \par\nobreak (and move it to be around only the lstlisting and not the \item also).

@PaulJ.Lucas yes, but then your keeptogether would not be semantically correctly named, would it? :) But of course you can put all this inside the definition of an arbitrarily named environment for your own use.

Maybe call it keepwithprevious (or something like that).

@PaulJ.Lucas as I said, you might call it as you like. If you're fine with keeptoprevious then go for it (I don't have a better idea myself)

I just realized that if the lstlisting has a [label=lst:foo], then the listing number is just a single number (like 10) as opposed to a number.number (chapter.listing, e.g., 14.10). I'm guessing it's because listings inside minipage get different numbering. How can I fix that so that the chapter-level listing numbers are used?

@PaulJ.Lucas for label to do something sensible you also have to use the caption option. For me it then prints 1.1 or similar. If that's not the case in your document you could try \counterwithin{lstlisting}{chapter} in your preamble. If that still doesn't work create an MWE reproducing your problem and ask a new question.
